# Visual Studio Code showing errors all over javascript files, javascript has no syntax errors (to my knowledge)

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code

So this weird thing with Visual studio code started happening with JS files, I'm getting random errors even in code that is commented out? not sure if this is a bug or my doing. I had someone open the folder from their computer and everything ran fine with no errors. The code on my computer runs fine as well, it's just these errors are annoying me and I wouldn't know if I'm actually doing something wrong in the future.

Here's an example file

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Declare Global Variable
  let admin = new Admin();
  let student = new Student();
  let inbox = new Inbox();
  let sentbox = new Sentbox();
  let v = new Validate();

  // Register Admin
  $("#regadminform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    const lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    const email = $("#adminEmail").val();

    admin.create(firstName, lastName, email).then(function (result) {
      if (!result.err) {
        // Sets user email
        localStorage.setItem("adminEmail", result.data.email);
        adminExist();
        $("#regadmin").modal("hide");
      } else {
        //error message
        alert(result);
      }
    });
  });

  // Get Selected User for 'To' Field
  $("#formTo").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var radioValue = $("input[name='to']:checked").val();
    $("#to").val(radioValue);
    $(".close").click();
  });

  $("#inboxTable").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.replace("../adminView.html");
  });

  // Get Selected User for 'CC' Field
  $("#formCC").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var radioValue = $("input[name='cc']:checked").val();
    $("#cc").val(radioValue);
    $(".close").click();
  });

  // Compose Email
  $("#composeForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    const from = localStorage.getItem("adminEmail");
    const to = $("#to").val();
    const cc = $("#cc").val();
    const subject = $("#subject").val();
    const body = $("#body").val();

    if (!v.isEmpty(cc, "CC")) {
      if (!v.isEmpty(subject, "Subject")) {
        if (!v.isEmpty(body, "Body")) {
          data = {
            from: from,
            to: to,
            cc: cc,
            subject: subject,
            body: body,
            viewed: false,
          };

          inbox.storeEmail(to, data).then(function (result) {
            if (!result.err) {
              sentbox.storeEmail(from, data).then(function (result) {
                if (!result.err) {
                  //result.message
                  window.location.replace("sentbox.html");
                } else {
                  //sentbox error message
                }
              });
            } else {
              //inbox error message
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Add a Admin
  $("#addadminform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const firstName = $("#first").val();
    const lastName = $("#last").val();
    const email = $("#email").val();

    admin.create(firstName, lastName, email).then(function (result) {
      if (!result.err) {
        $("#adminTable tbody").append(
          "<tr data-id=" +
            result.data._id +
            "><td >" +
            result.data.firstName +
            " " +
            result.data.lastName +
            "</td><td >" +
            result.data.email +
            "</td><td><i class='fa fa-times' id='close' aria-hidden='true'></i></td></tr>"
        );

        $("#first").val("");
        $("#last").val("");
        $("#email").val("");
      } else {
        //error message
      }
    });
    $(".close").click();
  });

  // Load 'To' table for admin selection
  $("#to").click(function (e) {
    // Empty Table
    $("#studentTo tbody").empty();

    // Load Table
    setTimeout(function () {
      student.getAll().then(function (result) {
        if (!result.err) {
          for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
            $("#studentTo tbody").append(
              "<tr><td>" +
                result.data[i].firstName +
                " " +
                result.data[i].lastName +
                "</td><td>" +
                result.data[i].email +
                '</td><td><input type="radio" name="to" class="to" value="' +
                result.data[i].email +
                '" required></td>'
            );
          }
        } else {
          //error message
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
  });

  // Load 'CC' table for admin selection
  $("#cc").click(function (e) {
    // Empty Table
    $("#adminCC tbody").empty();

    // Load Table
    setTimeout(function () {
      admin.getAll().then(function (result) {
        if (!result.err) {
          for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
            $("#adminCC tbody").append(
              "<tr><td>" +
                result.data[i].firstName +
                " " +
                result.data[i].lastName +
                "</td><td>" +
                result.data[i].email +
                '</td><td><input type="radio" name="cc" class="cc" value="' +
                result.data[i].email +
                '" required></td>'
            );
          }
        } else {
          //error message
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
  });

  // Get id of the email in the inbox and store it in localStorage
  $("#inboxTable tbody tr").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const emailID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    localStorage.setItem("emailID", emailID);
    window.location.replace("ViewingInboxItemsAdmin.html");
  });

  // Delete email in the inbox
  $("#inboxTable tbody").on("click", ".fa-times", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const emailID = $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-id");
    const email = localStorage.getItem("adminEmail");

    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this email?");

    if (r == true) {
      inbox.deleteEmail(emailID, email).then(function (result) {
        if (!result.err) {
          $("#inboxTable tbody tr[data-id='" + result.data._id + "']").remove();
        } else {
          //error message
        }
      });
    }
  });

  // Get id of the email in the sentbox and store it in localStorage
  $("#sentItemsTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const emailID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    localStorage.setItem("emailID", emailID);
    window.location.replace("ViewingSentItemsAdmin.html");
  });

  // Delete email in the sentbox
  $("#sentItemsTable tbody").on("click", ".fa-times", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const emailID = $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-id");
    const email = localStorage.getItem("adminEmail");

    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this email?");

    if (r == true) {
      sentbox.deleteEmail(emailID, email).then(function (result) {
        if (!result.err) {
          $(
            "#sentItemsTable tbody tr[data-id='" + result.data._id + "']"
          ).remove();
        } else {
          //error message
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

// Load inbox
function loadInbox() {
  let inbox = new Inbox();
  const email = localStorage.getItem("adminEmail");
  inbox.load(email).then(function (result) {
    if (!result.err) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        $("#inboxTable tbody").append(
          "<tr data-id=" +
            result.data[i]._id +
            "><td >" +
            result.data[i].email.from +
            "</td><td >" +
            result.data[i].email.subject +
            "</td><td><i class='fa fa-times' id='close' aria-hidden='true'></i></td></tr>"
        );
      }
    } else {
      //error message
    }
  });
}

// View an email in the inbox
function viewInboxEmail() {
  let inbox = new Inbox();
  const emailID = localStorage.getItem("emailID");
  const email = localStorage.getItem("adminEmail");
  inbox.viewEmail(emailID, email).then(function (result) {
    if (!result.err) {
      $("#From").val(result.data.from);
      $("#Cc").val(result.data.cc);
      $("#Subject").val(result.data.subject);
      $("#BodyText").val(result.data.body);
    } else {
      //error message
    }
  });
}

// Load the sentbox
function loadSentbox() {
  let sentbox = new Sentbox();
  const email = localStorage.getItem("adminEmail");
  sentbox.load(email).then(function (result) {
    if (!result.err) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        $("#sentItemsTable tbody").append(
          "<tr data-id=" +
            result.data[i]._id +
            "><td >" +
            result.data[i].email.from +
            "</td><td >" +
            result.data[i].email.subject +
            "</td><td><i class='fa fa-times' id='close' aria-hidden='true'></i></td></tr>"
        );
      }
    } else {
      //error message
    }
  });
}

// View an email in the sentbox
function viewSentboxEmail() {
  let sentbox = new Sentbox();
  const emailID = localStorage.getItem("emailID");
  const email = localStorage.getItem("adminEmail");
  sentbox.viewEmail(emailID, email).then(function (result) {
    if (!result.err) {
      $("#To").val(result.data.to);
      $("#From").val(result.data.from);
      $("#Cc").val(result.data.cc);
      $("#Subject").val(result.data.subject);
      $("#BodyText").val(result.data.body);
    } else {
      //error message
    }
  });
}

// List all the Students
function listAllStudents() {
  let student = new Student();

  student.getAll().then(function (result) {
    if (!result.err) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        $("#studentTable tbody").append(
          "<tr data-id=" +
            result.data[i]._id +
            "><td >" +
            result.data[i].firstName +
            " " +
            result.data[i].lastName +
            "</td><td >" +
            result.data[i].email +
            "</td><td><i class='fa fa-times' id='close' aria-hidden='true'></i></td></tr>"
        );
      }
    } else {
      //error message
    }
  });
}

// List all the Admins
function listAllAdmins() {
  let admin = new Admin();

  admin.getAll().then(function (result) {
    if (!result.err) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        $("#adminTable tbody").append(
          "<tr data-id=" +
            result.data[i]._id +
            "><td >" +
            result.data[i].firstName +
            " " +
            result.data[i].lastName +
            "</td><td >" +
            result.data[i].email +
            "</td><td><i class='fa fa-times' id='close' aria-hidden='true'></i></td></tr>"
        );
      }
    } else {
      //error message
    }
  });
}

// Check to see if Admin is stored in local storage
function adminExist() {
  const email = localStorage.getItem("adminEmail");
  let inbox = new Inbox();
  let sentbox = new Sentbox();

  if (email == null || email == "") {
    $("#regadmin").modal("show");
  } else {
    // Gets user email
    $("#userEmail").text(email);

    inbox.count(email).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (!result.err) {
        $("#adminInboxBadge").text(result.data.length);
      } else {
        //error message
      }
    });

    sentbox.count(email).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (!result.err) {
        $("#adminSentboxBadge").text(result.data.length);
      } else {
        //error message
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[Picture of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sIzx.png)

[Here is a picture of errors in comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtGQD.png)

It is clearly something to do with Visual Studio code (or so i think) has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: what are the errors? From the picture, the two `$` are highlighted - perhaps visual studio doesn't know what `$` is?

Comment: I would disable plugins and find out which one is causing it.

Comment: If you hover over the places in code with squiggly lines, it will tell you why it doesn't like it.

Comment: @Bravo Im assuming it is not recognizing jQuery? i installed it though and nothing.

Comment: @epascarello I disabled all of my plugins, still there

Comment: @DanOswalt i know, they are all "Cannot find x" which is not right because it is compiling, and finding it, and its functioning as it should

Comment: its weird because if i open the file I am linking to, the error will go away, once i close it, its back

Answer (score 0):

Go into the visual studio settings. Disable the ES-lint if you are using that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use jQuery in a browser you don't import it in the `.js` file.

You add a `script` tag in the HTML above it for jQuery.

The linter does only static analysis and has no knowledge of the script tags already executed.

The `$` variable is created in the jQuery JavaScript file. So is unknown to the linter.

If it annoys you a lot you can, like Sudarshan` mentions disable ES-lint for this project or globally.